# Selling American calls before ex date vs. exercising

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options

From reading Hull OFOD (among other references), I understand that early exercise makes sense for an American call option at time $t_n$ when $$D_n > K\Big[1-e^{-r\big(T-t_n\big)}\Big]$$
for a call option with strike $K$ paying dividend $D_n$ at time $t_n$.

What I'm struggling with is why, in a sense, does this require early exercise? In particular, if early exercise is optimal, then shouldn't that be "priced in" to the value of the call? That is, shouldn't the call price converge to the PV on the optimal path.

If it's not, and the call is priced cheap relative to early exercise value, wouldn't rational actors buy the american calls (for cheap) and exercise? So basically, why would exercise ever produce a different value from selling the call in the market?

(I am purposefully ignoring the practicalities of crossing bid/offer, cost of exercising, etc., as  (initially) I am trying to understand this from a theoretical perspective)

Comment: You are right: this optimal stopping strategy should be priced in by the model, otherwise as you mention there would be blatant arbitrage opportunities. And indeed, if the option is priced in by comparing it's continuation value versus the value you would get from exerciseming, at any future time, this will mechnaically be the case. To make sure your model behaves the right way, try pricing an American call with zero rates and huge div to be distributed half-way to expiry and see what hapmens.